# Impact of calling external C function on CPU time in OpenModelica

Tags: openmp, modelica, openmodelica

we have implemented an external delay function in C and we want to recall it in our Modelica model (transmission line). our goal is to accelerate the CPU time. unfortunately, it increased the CPU time.
My questions are:

1. Does calling the external function principally increase the simulation time in Modelica compared to the existing built-in delay?
2. Does use an external object in OpenModelica significantly increase the simulation time?
3. How to compile only our external function with Open MP (how we can add -fopenmp flag only for external function)?
   The following error (see the bekow Fig) was created when we did not use the above flag (as shown below figure), but using the flag from the beginning of compilation, made the simulation time longer while we have expected a shorter simulation time.
   PS: our function is compiled as a library in which we have included the -fopenmp flag.
   [image]
   [image]

Answer (score 2):

1. Does calling the external function principally increase the simulation time in Modelica compared to the existing built-in delay?

No. It's a very simple call and you are only allowed to use external function calls at well defined points in time in Modelica. You could have a problem if you introduce algebraic loops however.

2. Does use an external object in OpenModelica significantly increase the simulation time?

No. It's only a pointer. If something is slow, it is within the external object itself or how it is used.

3. How to compile only our external function with Open MP (how we can add -fopenmp flag only for external function): when linking source files? the following error was created when we did not use the above flag, but using the flag from the beginning of compilation, made the simulation time longer while we have expected a shorter simulation time. PS: our function is compiled as a library in which we have included the -fopenmp flag.

You compile the library ahead of time and add the -fopenmp flag to linker flags or in the Library annotation of the external function. Does the code run slower when using only 1 thread in OpenMP? Writing fast parallel code is hard and OpenMP hides a lot of the details, so it is hard to know why it runs slower.

Comment: thanks, @sjoelund.se, concerning your third point, how can we add -fopenmp flag to the linker flag

Comment: In OMEdit, under Tools -> OMC CLI you can input `setLinkerFlags("-fopenmp")`. This is only active for the current session though. Otherwise you can use an annotation: `external "C" annotation(Library="-fopenmp");` but this may not be portable across tools (maybe the compiler does not use the `-fopenmp` flag).

Comment: our external function contains a loop with 3 independent iterations, we decided to parallelize them (using 3 threads) and we expected improvement, however, the simulation took more time. do you have any idea? (we added linker flag" setLinkerFlags("-fopenmp"), we tried to change the environment variable OMP_NUM_THREAD but it didn't improve the CPU time).

Comment: You get an overhead to create a thread, which likely dwarfs the time it takes to complete 1 iteration. Do you know how long each iteration takes? Using SIMD might be better than threads. See https://lemire.me/blog/2020/01/30/cost-of-a-thread-in-c-under-linux/ for some estimate of thread creation+join (9~200 ms). Since this is for transmission lines, I assume the function is called many times; you get the overhead for each call of the function. You need either very many independent tasks or few tasks that take very long (seconds) to benefit from parallellization.